# Capybara + Selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, capybara, culerity

When I run my tests using Selenium, my one step fails and the page looks like this in the browser:

```
Internal Server Error

can't convert nil into String
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2010-08-18) at 127.0.0.1:50752
```

When I run it with culerity instead, I get the output:

```
    Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)
          /Users/yuval/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/culerity-0.2.15/lib/culerity/remote_object_proxy.rb:47:in `write'
etc...
```

When I run it without a js driver, it doesn't fail at that point at all (instead, it fails at a point when js is used, which is why I'm trying to run it with a js driver).

Any ideas?

Comment: can you run rails in development mode so you can get the full trace?  Cannot convert nil into string could be anywhere.

Comment: Actually, it runs just fine when I run it in the browser...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just faced te same problem, but found a solution.

If you try to open your browser with "http://127.0.0.1:3000" in development mode, instead of "http://localhost:3000", you should face the same problem.

In my case the problem was caused, because in my View file I used "request.domain" that returns nil if request is given in IP-like format, i.e. "http://127.0.0.1:50752".

Therefore, if somewhere in your view of helper methods you have something like this

```
link_to "Click me", :host => subdomain + "." + request.domain + request.port_string
```

you can change it to using helper method, like that:

```
link_to "Click me", :host => with_host(subdomain)
```

And helper like following:

```
  def with_host(subdomain)
    if request.domain.present?
      subdomain + "." + request.domain + request.port_string
    end
  end
```

That's the easiest solution that worked for me. Perhaps, you have something similar.